# What resources exist to measure a company's integrity?

Tags: stock-analysis, corporate-governance, ethical-investing

I have been on a search for companies with integrity. I have seen the (MSCI) ESG rating which is good, but I'm looking for indicators of integrity in a company separate from environmental factors.

I have reviewed the [Forbes America's 100 Most Trustworthy Companies](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kathryndill/2014/03/18/americas-100-most-trustworthy-companies/?sh=40d54b161e21), last published in 2014. Forbes hasn't published a newer version of this list.

I'm looking for something that would take into account things such as complaints to the SEC.

Are there any indexes, formulas, or algorithms that provide a measurable rating of integrity?

Comment: No, there aren't. There are various ESG compliance related measures, but they don't determine integrity. The closest thing to describe integrity of a company is what is referred to as "corporate governance". There are no measures of that. There IS the Harvard Project on Corporate Governance which has a web site with a lot of articles which might be of interest to you.

Comment: @EllieKesselman Thanks for the tip on the Harvard Project. I'll definitely check it out.